# InputID inside "for" loop

Tags: r, loops, shiny, counter

I'm fairly new at coding in R, and new at R Shiny, and would appreciate greatly any help.

I'm trying to design a simple counter app where I will need many action buttons. I would like to know if it's possible to assemble the action buttons' InputID's into a matrix, in order to create a loop in the "server" part of the app where I can refer to a specific InputID as a matrix element.

The final objective is to be able to click an action button in the app and not only show its value as a label after clicking, but also store that value in the matrix. I plan to do several different matrices, which is why I'd like to create a loop to shorten the code.

The code below is what I've done so far to show what I'm trying, but it doesn't work.

```
a1_q1 <- 0
a1_q2 <- 0
a1_q3 <- 0
a1_q4 <- 0

a2_q1 <- 0
a2_q2 <- 0
a2_q3 <- 0
a2_q4 <- 0

v1 <- c(a1_q1,a1_q2,a1_q3,a1_q4)
v2 <- c(a2_q1,a2_q2,a2_q3,a2_q4)
ma <- rbind(v1,v2)

inputbuttons <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
minputbuttons <- matrix(inputbuttons,nrow = 2,ncol = 4)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Scouting",
             tabPanel("Attack",
                      navlistPanel(
                        tabPanel("A",
                                 sidebarPanel(
                                   tags$b("A matrix")
                                 ),
                                 mainPanel(
                                   tags$b("Quality: 1-4"),
                                   br(),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[1,1], a_q1,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[1,2], a_q2,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[1,3], a_q3,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[1,4], a_q4,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                                   br(),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[2,1], a_q1,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[2,2], a_q2,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[2,3], a_q3,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;"),
                                   actionButton(minputbuttons[2,4], a_q4,
                                                style = "width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:blue; color:white;")
                                 )
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  for (i in 1:2){
    for (j in 1:4){
      observeEvent(
        input$minputbuttons[i,j],
        ma[i,j] <<- ma[i,j] + 1,
        updateActionButton(session,minputbuttons[i,j],label = ma[i,j])
      )
    }
  }
}

shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated!
V~

Comment: Based on what I've read, I believe you're looking for https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderUI.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for loops doesn't work on server side for this kind of things, you should try `lapply` instead

```r
library(shiny)
x <- letters
ui <- function(request){
    tagList(
        lapply(
            x, 
            function(x){
                actionButton(
                    inputId = x, 
                    label = x
                )
            }
        )   
    )
}

server <- function(
    input, 
    output, 
    session
){
    lapply(
        x,
        function(x){
            observeEvent( input[[x]] , {
                print(x)
            })
        }
    )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The issue isn’t the `for` loop itself, it’s that the loop variable is modified. This can be fixed by using a local copy of the loop variable inside the loop. Though using `lapply` etc is probably nicer.